# How to show and hide actionbar for fragments using viewpager

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I have fragment A, B, C, D inside a viewpager.
I want to hide the actionbar in fragment A and show the actionbar for the rest of the fragments.

Any Ideas?
Thanks.

Edit:
Tried the following and still had the actionbar show up in all the fragments.

```
@Override 
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
if (position == 0) {
  mActionBar.hide();
} else {
  mActionBar.show();
}
}
```

Pretty much when you open the activity with the viewpager I am want Fragment A to show up with no actionbar but when i swipe to view the other fragments I want the actionbar to be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fragments you want to show the Action Bar :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    actionBar.show();
}
```

In Fragments you dont want to show the Action Bar :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    actionBar.hide();
}
```

For a ViewPager :

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int selectedPage) {
        // Check the selectedPage here and then show and 
        // hide the actionBar accordingly. 

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: This won't work when using a viewpager.
Actionbar will show in all the fragments.

Comment: Ah! ignored that. In that case, you could use `onPageSelected (int position)` method to check the selected page and hide and show the action bar accordingly.

Comment: Just tried the following and the actionbar still shows up in all the fragments.
@Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                mActionBar.hide();
            } else {
                mActionBar.show();
            }
        }

Comment: Please put the code in the question itself. Also, please explain what should I do with it ?

Comment: Thanks its a little choppy the the actionbar shows and hides but looks like its heading to the right direction. I was implementing OnPageChangeListener to FragmentPagerAdapter but that wasn't doing anything.

Comment: To better the choppy part, hide/show the action bar ~500ms (you can experiment on this time) after the page has changed. The animation stutters a bit if you do multiple things at the same time.